# Python PIP for absolute beginner (add Paths)

Tags: python, pip

I am NOT a coder.  I was trying to follow an online video when I stumbled on the PIP command for python.  I have Python 3.9.

In the command prompt, if I type in PIP..I get

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Because I TRY to RTFM, another suggestion mentions using python as a command

> C:\Users\TL>python get-pip.py

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the
> Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App
> Execution Aliases.

Now I feel stuck.  I am just trying write basic python code on a Windows 10 computer.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Upon futher review, this question is partially answered.

How do I add these paths to bee seen???

> C:\Users\TL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
> C:\Users\TL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

By now, I have seen it mentioned a few time with no real explanation of where this is added.

ADENDUM:
I followed the instruction from the link below.  The paths were added.  PIP "Shows" as installed successfully. but the PIP command does not work.  See picture

[image: Screenshot of paths and CMD]

Comment: did you even install python?

Comment: Make sure you've installed python correctly and it is [added to your path](https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/) (random link found googling it). You may also need to restart your shell/command prompt for the changes to take place.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.4+ comes with pip: you don't need get-pip.py

Generally speaking, unless you've activated a virtualenv (which you haven't), you should prefer to always use `python -m pip` as you then have full control about which Python you're installing packages into. This is more commonly a problem when you have more than one Python installed

So, you want to use

```
python -m pip --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your problem, but I am assuming that you are using CMD. Check if you added Python to the windows path.
you can follow the steps in this link
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: Thanks.  That got me one step closer.  I am still unable to "see" my PIP version.  I can't seem to add details here.  I will append my original post.

Comment: Assuming you have python installed, please follow this path: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/3

Comment: on cmd enter the command `python`
then `import pip` later `pip.__version__`
After this you can run python from your command line. And if you want to return to the normal command line use the command `quit()`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more user-friendly to use a terminal window than a command prompt like Jupyter as an alternative.

However, if you're looking to use Python using your Windows command prompt then you can type in `Python3.9` , `python` or `python3`. Then, use the `pip` command to install any Python dependencies and libraries.